# Modify the value of a global variable from a inner class

Tags: android, kotlin

So i have a class

```
class createLobby : AppCompatActivity() {
    var invited = ArrayList<String>()
    private class myCustomAdapter(context: Context, users:ArrayList<User>): BaseAdapter() {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
            invited.add(mUsers.get(position).idUser)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that i can't modify invited, it says unresolved reference

I have tried to change `invited.add(mUsers.get(position).idUser)`  for:

```
this.invited...
createLobby.invited...
((createLobby) stuff here)
```

but it hasn't work, any ideas or help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to mark your inner class with `inner`.  See here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html

So you would have:

```
class createLobby : AppCompatActivity() {
    var invited = ArrayList<String>()
    private inner class myCustomAdapter(context: Context, users:ArrayList<User>): BaseAdapter() {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
            invited.add(mUsers.get(position).idUser)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: omg i read that and i forgot to write the inner, give me a min and let me try it, thanks!